# Can't see image when using css

Tags: html, css, web

I am learning html+css right now, and got in trouble. this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>No</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="homework.css">
    </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Поисковые системы</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><h1>Google.com</h1></li>
                        <ul class="gog">
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com.ua/">Поиск</li>
                    <li><a href="https://images.google.com/">Картинки</li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.by/maps/@">Карты</li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/drive/">Google Диск</li>
                    <li><a href="https://translate.google.com.ua/">Переводчик</li>
                        </ul>
                </ul>
        </body>
</html>
```

and this is css code

```
.gog{
    list-style-image: url("images/1.gif");
}
```

so why can't I see an image I wrote in class `gog` for five li? Where is my mistake?

Comment: It is working as expected. Check the path of the image. also, check the console for errors.

Comment: Code is fully Working.. Check image path...

Comment: @BlackPanther path isn t false, i checked

Comment: @SankarRaj no errors i have, path is true

Comment: @sekeke6 are you sure it is gif? also share that image file here.

Answer (score 0):

Its problem in your path

```css
.gog{
    list-style-image: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fugue/icon/tick-circle-frame.png");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>No</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="homework.css">
    </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Поисковые системы</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><h1>Google.com</h1></li>
                        <ul class="gog">
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com.ua/">Поиск</li>
                    <li><a href="https://images.google.com/">Картинки</li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.by/maps/@">Карты</li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/drive/">Google Диск</li>
                    <li><a href="https://translate.google.com.ua/">Переводчик</li>
                        </ul>
                </ul>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yaaaaaaaa but i have picture in the folder.

Comment: C:\Users\oleg\Desktop\new folder\images

Comment: html+css are in new folder

Comment: you are using external css